# How to view the entire set of changes made to svn for the last 'n' days?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to view the entire set of changes made to svn for the last 'n' days?. I couldn't find a reference in the document though

Comment: I believe SVN generally works on revisions, and not days. So you would have to look at the revision list for the last `n` days to determine which revision number you want to look back at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify dates for `svn log` to operate on, so if you want the last `n` days you only need to calculate the date of `n` days before today, then feed it to svn like this:

```
svn log -r "{2010-05-23}:HEAD"
```

See also the output of `svn log -h` for details on the log options.

Answer (score 2):

In the TortoiseSVN log dialog, you can either filter the already fetched and shown revisions by date with the date buttons on the top left, or you can use the "Show all" button on the bottom left and use the "Show Range" button menu. In the range dialog, you can enter the date range to fetch the log entries for in the svn date format.
For example:

```
{"2002-02-17 15:30"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your client you could use the Blame utility and use an old revision of the file you wanted to look at. It would show who made the changes and at what revision. Like webdestroya said SVN works on revisions so although you won't be able to see the exact date there will still be a timeline.

If your using the command line then its svn blame or svn annotate

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well..

```
>backdate=\`date +%Y-%m-%d --date="10 days ago"\` ; svn log -r "{$backdate}:HEAD"
```