# Recommended Way To See SVN Differences Statistics Between Two Days?

Tags: svn

I'm writing a very simple program on my company's internal website that shows the number of svn commits, line changes, and file changes between two dates. I made the actual page but I'm having trouble trying to figure out the best way to execute the comparison. I was hoping someone could recommend a way to tackle this.

Edit: SVN commands are okay but it seems like there should be an easier way to get these numbers directly. I can do the parsing but would API just give me the numbers?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926710/how-to-view-the-entire-set-of-changes-made-to-svn-for-the-last-n-days or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282802/how-can-i-view-all-historical-changes-to-a-file-in-svn

Comment: Do you prefer to parse SVN command output or to run API (Subversion has very nice API with bindings to a lot of languages, incl. Java, Perl, Python)?

Comment: I think API is the way to go for me. I only want numbers. Thanks for mentioning API. I'm only been looking at svn commands all day and I "hate" them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found to do this was to use PHP to call SVN commands and parse through the data with regex.  It was a lot to learn and it could get slow but it worked.